# Extract string between other strings using RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the string between `site:` and `.com` using pure `RegEx`, e.g.,

```
string = "site:linkedin.com/in"
result = "linkedin"

string = "site:instagram.com"
result = "instagram"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, check https://regex101.com/r/g5bJZr/3

```
(?<=site:).*?(?=.com)
```

It use *look around* advanced regex technique